# R Studio - remove duplicate and one column is greater than another column

Tags: r

I want to remove duplicated "ID", and leave the records when "value1" is greater than "value2". I try to avoid for loop because I have large data frame. Appreciate your time!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dplyr library, you could  use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
filter(value1 > value2)
```

This will show all of the rows that value1 is higher than the corresponding value2.

From your question it is not clear if this is sufficient to remove all of the duplicate ID values- how you handle that will depend on what your goal is and the structure of your data (are there ID's that have multiple meeting your criteria?  if so do you want to keep all of them or just the first/last/one with highest value/some other criteria)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did a filter like you suggested, then I remove duplicate. It works for my data

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df, value1 > value2)
```